# laravel 4.2 got 500 error in some routes from localhost xampp

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-4

I got a cloned laravel project installed in my localhost xampp in my win10 laptop. I was wondering that some of the routes got 500 internal server error. I guess this is in my .htaccess

```
<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE>
#For REST support
       Allow from all
 </Limit>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options +FollowSymLinks
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /ski/skitrip/

    AddType video/ogg .ogv
    AddType video/mp4 .mp4
    AddType video/webm .webm

    ##
    ## You may need to uncomment the following line for some hosting environments,
    ## if you have installed to a subdirectory, enter the name here also.
    ##
    # RewriteBase /

    ##
    ## Black list protected files
    ##
    RewriteRule themes/.*/(layouts|pages|partials)/.*.htm index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule /ski/skitrip/uploads/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]

    ##
    ## White listed folders and files
    ##
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.js
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.ico
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.jpg
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.jpeg
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.gif
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.css
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.less
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.scss
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.pdf
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.png
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.swf
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.txt
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.xml
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.xls
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.eot
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.woff
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.ttf
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.svg
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.wmv
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.avi
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.mov
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.mp4
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.webm
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.ogg
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !docs/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !themes/.*
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,NC]

    ##
    ## Standard routes
    ##
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

i tried to modified it but it's not working. any idea?

Comment: Post the laravel log. It is accessing the server. 500 http code are internal server errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try these one

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```